# Converting getElementbyID to Form Field value

Tags: javascript, form-fields

I am using a prescribed javascript from the supplier of a 'paid for' slideshow. It gives me a value by getElementbyID() using their API. The value changes each time a different image is chosen to 'view large'.

I need the value (e.g. IMG_0001.jpg) to appear in a specific 'hidden' Form Field to be carried forward when the form is submitted. I can successfully place it any where else on the page, with a DIV tag carrying the appropriate id, but I do not know how to write the value into the Form Field.

Is there another way to call the value (other than with a DIV and id) so that it can be entered into the 'value' of the Form Field?

The Form Field has to be 'hidden' and the name has to be 'item_number', otherwise any other attributes such as id, class or value can be made to suit.

Comment: please write more clear..

Comment: re-worded as per request

Answer (score 0):

You should show what the 'id' you are referring to is in your question so we don't have to guess, but I suspect you're saying you have

```
<img id="somename" src="IMG_0001.jpg" />
```

then in your javascript you've got

```
var selected_item = document.getElementById('somename');
```

now you want to put the src tag into a form

```
var form = document.getElementById('myForm');
var new_input = document.createElement('input');
new_input.type='hidden';
new_input.name='somename';
new_input.value=selected_item.getAttribute('src');
form.append(new_input);
```

That will add a hidden attribute to the hidden field to the form. Of course, you haven't given us the name of your form, it's ids, what you're trying to add, or really where you're getting the data from, so much of this will have to be updated for your situation.

Comment: Hi @pedalpete , Thanks for your response which I think is probably just about getting me there if I could get it clarified. I am struggling with learning code. Maybe if you could look at the test page on-line, all the questions you raise will be answered by looking at my page source in its entirity. The page is at; [link](http://www.46thpreston.org.uk/simpletest/)